# android - javah doesn't find my class

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-ndk, javah

I am having troubles generating the C header file for JNI using `javah`.

Here's the script I use while standing in the `<project-dir>\bin` directory:

```
javah -classpath C:\PROGRA~2\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-8\android.jar com.test.JniTest
```

As return I get:

```
ERROR: Could not find class file for 'com.test.JniTest'.
```

Even though the class `JniTest` certainly is in `\com\test`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You specify the classpath to contain *only* `android.jar`.

You also need to include the location where your classes are stored. In your case it is the current directory, so you need to use `.` (separated by `;` on Windows). The invocation should look like this:

```
javah -classpath C:\PROGRA~2\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-8\android.jar;. com.test.JniTest
```

Comment: just adding, apparently you have to be outside the directory of the actual file. You can't just specify the name of the file.

Comment: Error: no classes specified errror cant get inside android.jar

Answer (score 18):

If you are on Linux or MAC-OS, use `":"` to separate the directories for `classpath` rather than `";"` character: Example:

```
javah -cp /Users/Android/android-sdk/platforms/android-xy/android.jar:. com.test.JniTest
```

Comment: that : in linux saved me :P

Answer (score 10):

You should change the directory to `<project-dir>\bin\classes`; then, run the following command:

```bsh
javah -classpath C:\PROGRA~2\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-8\android.jar;. com.test.JniTest
```

I'm using the following command file to generate headers:
`jHdr.cmd` on my desktop:

```
@echo on
SET PLATFORM=android-8
SET ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Android\android-sdk
SET PRJ_DIR=D:\Workspaces\sqLite\raSQLite
SET CLASS_PKG_PREFIX=ra.sqlite
cd %PRJ_DIR%\bin\classes
javah -classpath %ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\platforms\%PLATFORM%\android.jar;.  %CLASS_PKG_PREFIX%.%~n1
pause
```

adjust variables to your needs ...

 put this file on your desktop, then drag you .java file from eclise to `jHdr.cmd`, result is under %PRJ_DIR%\bin\classes directory