# Javah cannot find khronos.opengles.GL10

Tags: android, classpath, native-code, javah

There are similar questions addressed here, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985336/javah-cant-find-class-android-ndk) one, but I've already checked their answers and, after implementing them, `javah` is still unable to find the `javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.*;` configuration.

I have my classpath (in eclipse) edited to include the Android SDK API 10 .jar file, so this should work. Is there an external environment variable I need to edit? I've already tried echoing out $CLASSPATH, which appears to be blank, so I have no idea what the issue is here,
and after exporting it to the location of my `android.jar` file, it still doesn't work.

Thus, I'm at a loss here as of what to do.

What could be done to solve for this? It appears the only issue really is this library, and nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For android-ndk-r8b and windows 7( 64 bit ) you must write -bootclasspath and point exactly to android.jar file and optionally -classpath. for example:

```
javah -classpath bin/classes -bootclasspath "C:\android-sdk\platforms\android-8\android.jar" com.example.SanAngeles.DemoRenderer
```