# Javah still won't find class files in OSX / Android Studio

Tags: java, android, macos, java-native-interface, javah

Having referred to --> [Javah error while using it in JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986262/javah-error-while-using-it-in-jni)

...and --> [android - javah doesn't find my class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635624/android-javah-doesnt-find-my-class)

...I still can't get `javah` to work.  Specifically...

My java class is located here:

```
/Users/HKS/Code/MusicPlayer-Android/dspLibrary/src/main/java/com/company/audio/LibDSP.java`
```

From this folder...

```
/Users/HKS/Code/MusicPlayer-Android/dspLibrary/src/main/java/`
```

...I've tried running...

```
javah com.company.audio.LibDSP
javah -classpath . com.company.audio.LibDSP
javah -classpath /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk/platforms/android-16/android.jar:. -jni com.company.audio.LibDSP
```

...I've also tried this from within the actual folder containing the `.java` file...

```
javah LibDSP
javah -classpath . LibDSP
```

All give the usual...

```
error: cannot access com.company.audio.LibDSP
class file for com.company.audio.LibDSP not found
javadoc: error - Class com.company.audio.LibDSP not found.
Error: No classes were specified on the command line.  Try -help.
```

Any ideas?

Incidental verbose logs show something strange in the search path...

```
[ Search Path: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines....../Contents/Classes/charsets.jar//Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/platforms/android-16/android.jar:. ]
```

Notice how there seems to be no separator for the ones added with `-classpath`. I've tried pre-pending ":" and it makes no difference. I'm assuming this is a bug in the verbose output rather than the core functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it! It needs the compiled class, not the source. Also, the class folder - `./build/intermediates/classes/debug` is hidden from the project in Android Studio.

This is the line that finally worked for me. From my module's root folder (`/Users/HKS/Code/MusicPlayer-Android/dspLibrary/`):

```
javah -classpath /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk/platforms/android-16/android.jar:./build/intermediates/classes/debug -jni -d src/main/jni -force com.company.audio.LibDSP
```

Note the `-d` flag is the output folder, and `-force` ensures it overwrites any existing files.