# Error: cannot access android.app.Activity class file for android.app.Activity not found

Tags: android, android-ndk

I've looked at the similar questions at: [Javah Error android.app.Activity not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483959/javah-error-android-app-activity-not-found)

and

[Javah still won't find class files in OSX / Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26274155/javah-still-wont-find-class-files-in-osx-android-studio)

But my error still isn't resolved. The first link suggests adding Android 8, I don't have Android 8 as I am building for Android 15 or higher. So I do have the correct Android15 in my classpath.

The other link isn't too specific for a beginner like myself.

This is what I have so far as my Javah file, I've included additional classes into my classpath to try to fix the error. This is my one Javah line:

```
javah  -classpath <path-to-sdk>/Android/sdk/platforms/android-15.android.jar:<path-to-sdk>Android/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar:<path-to-sdk>/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/libs/android-support-v4.jar:./build/intermediates/classes/debug  -d src/main/jni com.tawu.MainActivity
```

By adding "android-support-v7-appcompat.jar" and "android-support-v4.jar" I thought it would fix the issue but it hasn't.

I appreciate any help and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The error was solved by removing the .jar files and actually using the CORRECT path to the Android SDK version.

This ended up working:
    javah -classpath ./build/intermediates/classes/debug://Android/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/libs  -d src/main/jni

:)